# SQL Server: convert and merge separate date and time columns (both integers)

Tags: sql, datetime, sql-server-2014

I am working on a query, where I have to fill a table's column (`[Result_DateTime]`) with datetime values.

The datetime based on two columns, both integer. One contains the date and the other is the time, as it is.

[image: Table data example]

As you can see from the picture, it is a bit difficult to merge and convert these values to an actual datetime, because of the way they are stored. Mainly the time value causing problems.

I concluded how to convert the date column:

```
CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(20200131, 8))
```

but then I got stuck - what to do with the time and how to merge the two into one datetime effectively?

Using function STUFF looks nasty...

Could you help me out please? I am using SQL Server 2014

Answer (score 0):

Below is one method to do it:

```
SELECT CAST(Convert(DATE, LEFT(DATEUPDT, 8)) AS VARCHAR(10)) +' '+CAST (TIMEUPDT/100 AS VARCHAR(4)) + ':' + CAST(TIMEUPDT%(100 * (TIMEUPDT/100)) AS VARCHAR(10))+':00' 
FROM TEST_TABLE_TIME;
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is a good starting point. But when I test it, sometimes I get 'Divide by zero error' and truncated times. Mainly when I test with time values like 0 or 700.

Comment: Yes those conditions needs to be handled using case.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found one solution. What I tried is to avoid using varchar conversions because of how the time column's zeros are cut off. However, I am not convinced that this is the most effective way to do so:

```
DECLARE @DateInt int = 20200131
DECLARE @TimeInt int = 345  -- 03:45:00
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(@DateInt, 8)) + 
CAST(DATEADD(second, FLOOR(@TimeInt / 100) * 3600 + FLOOR(@TimeInt / 1) % 100 * 60, 0) as datetime)
```

I was testing it with various time values, it is working.